# is the Bitmain X3 compatible with Monero

Tags: mining, cryptonight, cryptonight-lite

Will Bitmain X3 be able to mine Monero?

Answer (score 1):

No the hardfork changed the algorithm to prevent ASIC usage.

[Source](https://getmonero.org/2018/03/28/a-scheduled-protocol-upgrade-is-planned-for-April-6-2018-03-28.html)

Comment: i have heard it will mine it but with  a lower hash rate?